# Are the layout constraints equivalent?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to understand `ConstraintSet`. Will these two approaches result in the same layout constraint?

JAVA

```
constraintSet.connect(textViewA.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, textViewB.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewA"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewB"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@id/textViewB"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are equivalent assuming that `textViewA` and `textViewB` references are what they appear to reference. In the XML `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewB"` means "take the right side of this view (textViewA) and attach it to the left side of textViewB." The Java code means the same.

I suggest that you use start/end instead of left/right if you are at the right API level. `ConstraintLayout` has had some issues with left/right in code and the designer in the past and, IMO, start/end are preferred.